Upgrading to 24.04.1 Failing "...../kazam/ubuntu jammy Release" Does Not Have a Release File"
I am trying to upgrade from 22.04.5 LTS to 24.04 and I keep getting asked to update all apps.  First MySql key was invalid and I fixed that.  Now I am getting a reference to an app, kazam that I do not have anywhere on my system.  I want to upgrade to new Ubuntu, how do I get around or through this issue?
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/sylvain-pineau/kazam/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


A human told the system to add that apt source. Perhaps they wanted to try kazam. If you don't use it, then delete that apt source. Best practice is to disable ALL non-Ubuntu sources, and to uninstall ALL non-Ubuntu software. This gives you the highest probability of a successful release-upgrade. Afterward, you can re-add non-Ubuntu software if you wish. The #1 cause of broken release-upgrades that we see at AskUbuntu is non-Ubuntu software.
